# Is this a reasonably efficient method for querying/filtering the results of a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am combining a large number of search parameters in my queries and am therefore required to distill the data by running subsequent queries as well as filtering the results.

I am wondering if this would be a reasonably efficient method for querying/filtering the results of a query? If it's not a great option, then I'd appreciate some input since I know of several other (relatively simple) ways to go about it but I don't have a handle on all the nuances just yet.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ..."); 
 $stmt->bindValue(':Column', $Column, PDO::PARAM_STR);        
 $stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->columnCount()) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
        echo $row['c2fproduct_id'].' '.$row['Price'].' '.$row['Color'], "<br />"; 

        $substmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM style WHERE..."); 
        $substmt->bindValue(':Column', $Column, PDO::PARAM_STR);        
        $substmt->execute();
    }     

    if ($substmt->columnCount())  {
        while($subrow = $substmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        echo $subrow['id'].' '.$subrow['colors'], "<br />"; 
        }
    }   
  }   
}
```